# CSS Vertical Navigation letters

Tags: html, css, sass, navigation, vertical-alignment

Im extremely new, trying to accomplish a vertical navigation, where even the links and letters are vertical.
So far ive made everything vertical however now im having issues with the links squishing together because they have no space?

In picture 1 you see what im trying to accomplish and picture 2 is what ive done so far.

Not sure whether display should be block or inline-block also..

vertical nav
[image: vertical nav]

[image: pic2]

Here's my code: the html (with php)

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="navigation__left">
      <a class="header__logo" href="<?= home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
    </div>
    <nav aria-label="primary">
      <div class="inner">
        <?php dazy_top_nav(); ?>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

The scss:

```
.menu {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  padding: rem-calc(100 20);
  list-style: none;
  font-size: rem-calc(22);
  text-align: center;
  @include breakpoint($medium) {
    margin: rem-calc(0 -15);
    padding: 0;
    font-family: $regular;
    font-size: unquote("clamp(0.938rem, 0.5vw + 0.8rem, 1.375rem)");
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: unquote("clamp(1.25rem, 0.9vw + 1rem, 2.125rem)");
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
    text-align: initial;
  }
  &__item {
    padding: rem-calc(10 0);
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    @include breakpoint($medium) {
      padding: rem-calc(20 0);
    }
  }
  &__link {
    color: $black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

and:

```
.navigation {
  height: 100%;
  width: 49px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  .inner {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: $white-fever;
    transition: transform linear 300ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    @include breakpoint($medium) {
      padding: 0;
      transform: translateY(0);
      flex-direction: row;
      background-color: transparent;
      position: relative;
      visibility: visible;
      transition: none;
    }
    .is-open & {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution would be to use a combination of both:

- `writing-mode: vertical-lr;`
- `transform: rotate(0.5turn);`

Here is a quick exemple:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(0.5turn)
}


/* Next two rules are just here to show you the space taken by the links */
li a {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

li:nth-child(odd) a {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item 10</a></li>
</ul>
```

More informations:
[writing-mode definition on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

> The writing-mode CSS property sets whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically, as well as the direction in which blocks progress. When set for an entire document, it should be set on the root element (html element for HTML documents).